# Adding text to each image item of a Gallery in Android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have a image Gallery, and i want to show the last modified data below each image, but nothing is shown in the TextView (but yes in the ImageView). This is my adapter.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Drawable[] pics;
    private String[] filePaths;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, Drawable[] pics, String[] filePaths) {
        this.context=context;
        this.pics =pics;
        this.filePaths=filePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pics.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v=view;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;


        if(v==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
        }

        imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
        textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.galleryTextView);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(115, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

        File f=new File(filePaths[i]);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date lastModified=new Date(f.lastModified());

        imageView.setImageDrawable(pics[i]);
        textView.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(lastModified));

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

And this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/galleryImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/galleryTextView"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As I said, the image is shown, but there is no text below it.

Comment: Try to Toast or Log last modified. May be you are getting empty.

Comment: I have a Log showing the date, and it's ok

Comment: @Doruko you have to return the view not the imageView ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning ImageView instead of View(Layout).

Use this code

```
return v;
```

Comment: Damn it, I didn't notice that... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Return

```
return v;
```

instead of

```
return imageView;
```